# Install tensorflow from sources

Tags: tensorflow

For resolving "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GRUCell'" i was told to install tensorflow from sources. I tried a lot from the tensorflow website but it did not happen. I need to execute sequence to sequence models.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Please add more information about your system, OS, what steps you already followed and what errors your are encountering.

Comment: System specifications:
Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware
disk space -110 GB
RAM -1 GB
python 2.7. I followed until configuration. please give ur email so that i will send my errors screenshot